# Set image URL for custom image loading animation from different class

Tags: ios, swift, caanimation

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I'm still pretty new to Swift, so I can't figure it out. Basically, I have followed [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/94302/implement-circular-image-loader-animation-cashapelayer) tutorial to implement a custom loading animation. It's working fine in my app with the demo image, however I can't figure out how to add a URL from a different class.

I need to be able to set the url of the image in `viewDidAppear` and this is also when I would like the animation to start.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an NSURL for the URL of the image you want to get.

Then create an instance of NSData with contentsOfUrl to get the URL as data.

Then create a UIImage with the NSData

Then update the imageView with the new image

```
let myPhotoUrl = NSURL(string: "http://myfancypics.com/abc.jpg")

let photoDataFromUrl = NSData(contentsOfURL: myPhotoUrl!)

let myImage = UIImage(data: photoDataFromUrl)

imageView.image = myImage
```